# unable to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

when I was prompted to upgrade my OS to 16.04, it took more than 12 hours and post that my system went unresponsive without any apparent errors. When I rebooted i noticed that the system is still in 14.04 version. 
It might help you to know that when I first tried moving from windows I could not install 16.04 directly. So I installed 14.04.

Below are my system configurations
Dell E6420
RAM - 7.8 GiB
Processor - Intel® Core™ i5-2540M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4 
OS type - 64-bit
Disk space - 306.5 GB

Comment: Why couldn't you install 16.04 directly?  What was the problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the error message.

Comment: Like I said, there were no errors in the console but the system was unresponsive to key strokes for a very long time when I was forced to restart and when it restarted it was still running 14.04